# Possible for $\int_\mathbb{R} x dx$ to converge?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

$\int_\mathbb{R} x dx$ does not converge since $\int_\mathbb{R} x dx =\int_{-\infty}^1 xdx+\int_1^\infty x dx$, and $\int_1^\infty xdx$ does not converge.

I am wondering if there's *alternative* definition of integral under which $\int_\mathbb{R} x dx$ converges. An example from series, not integral, is convergence of Cesaro mean. I am asking this because it seems to me that, since at least we have $\int_{-L}^L xdx = 0$, we might "hope" that $x$ "converges" on the whole real line.

Comment: You get zero in the sense of the Cauchy principal value.

Comment: $$\text{P.V.}\int_{\mathbb R}x\ dx=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^Rx\ dx=0$$ Basically what Ian said

Comment: iff the integral converges, it will converge to it's Cauchy principal value.